# If JavaScript enabled submit form, else navigate to view

Tags: jsf, jsf-2.2

Is there a JSF-component which

a) acts like a h:commandLink **if JavaScript is enabled** and does a form submit

b) acts like a h:link **if JavaScript is disabled** and simply navigates to a given page?

**Background:** 
I develop a barrier-free webapplication. The form submit is a convenience function. But users with inactive JavaScript should at least navigate to the page to which the bean action of the form submit would redirect a JavaScript-enabled webbrowser.

**My problem:**
h:commandLink does nothing if JavaScript is disabled.

Comment: then just use h:commandButton! why not ?

Comment: JSF will do a lot of nothing if Javascript is disabled. JSF is heavily dependent on javascript: There is no JSF without js. Almost anything that involves the client communicating with the server-side requires js.

Comment: @Tarik: That was my first thought but I have to use GET-Links because there is another h:commandButton which should be the default when hitting <enter>

Comment: @Kolossus: You can't generally say that. 3 rules and you are free of JavaScript in JSF:  Don't use h:commandLink, don't use f:param in h:commandButton, don't use actionListeners.

Comment: @Ginkgochris - "JSF is heavily dependent on javascript"? I can generally say that. Very very few people will take on a JSF dependency just to display static pages with hyperlinks. Why bother? If your objective is to not interact with the server side and do only client-side/static business, JSF has no purpose. "No commandLink, f:param, commandButton"? So basically, no server-side communication? What would be  the benefit of the JSF framework in that instance then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible solution:
Write your own CommandLink-Renderer (Mojarra: com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.CommandLinkRenderer) which evaluates a href-Param and sets it as a href="JF-Outcome" instead of the href="#"

```
<h:commandLink value="Klick me" action="#{beanAction}">
    <f:param name="href" value="JSF-Outcome" />
</h:commandLink>
```

Non JavaScript users follow the link, the others post the form.